# How would you let screen or byobu kill all detached sessions?

Tags: ubuntu, session, centos, gnu-screen

I don't want them any more.

I tried `screen --help` and didn't find some command suite for this task.

Is there some way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to loop over each detached screen session and issue the "quit" command.  The following one-liner would do it for you:

```
screen -ls | grep "Detached" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i screen -X -S {} quit
```

Comment: does this mean that you need to login at byobu and run this command?

Answer (score 0):

Include this function in your .bash_profile:

```
killd () {
echo yo
for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]\{5\}')
do
screen -S "${session}" -X quit;
done
}
```

to run it, call `killd`